# HttpClient и взаимодействие со страницей 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, android, java, android-asynctask, httpclient

В AsyncTask'е читаю из веба текстовый файл и записываю его на внутренний носитель Андроид устройства. Все работает как следует, за одним нюансом - если файл с веб-адреса удалить - программа, не моргнув глазом, сжирает встроенную на сервере страницу 404 и выдает html потроха за искомый текстовый файл.

Мои попытки обратить внимание на то, что тут есть некоторая ошибка - игнорируется,
запрос:

```
Log.d("AsyncTask говорит","отклик: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Дает отклик "200" (что соответствует полностью адекватному контенту).

От безысходности, я даже страницу 404 переделал, заменил все содержание на одно слово "error" и ставил условие отказ записи файла после нахождения такого слова, но даже это не сработало (строка не ловится, вероятно, проблема в спец. символах внутри строки).

Люди добрые, может кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите как образумить код, иначе, случись что - так и будет ведь жрать 404.html, причмокивая.

Ниже рабочий код для чтения и записи текстового файла:

```
//загружаем текст для пункта меню
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(MenuSalesTextUrl);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        MenuSalesTex = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        Log.d("AsyncTask говорит","отклик: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

//записываем текстовый файл для пункта меню во внутреннюю папку приложения
    if (MenuSalesTex != null){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos =  context.openFileOutput(
                context.getString(R.string.OffMenuSaleTextFilename),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(MenuSalesTex.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }          
    }
```

UPD: Посидел в тишине и придумал решение задачи.
Нам ведь нужно выяснить наличие файла на сервере, а это делается так:

```
        try {
          HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
          HttpURLConnection con = 
                  (HttpURLConnection) new URL(MenuSalesTextUrl).openConnection();
          con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
          int FileExistCheck = con.getResponseCode();
          Log.d("AsyncTask говорит","con.getResponseCode(): " + con.getResponseCode());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Соотв. перед загрузкой файла нужно поставить условие

```
    if ( FileExistCheck == 200 ){}
```

200 - исключительное условие наличия файла строго по указанному адресу.
Соотв. если будет редирект на 404 страницу, код будет отличаться, например в моем случае при отсутствии файла на месте я получаю код 302.
На всякий случай, [коды тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_200#200).

Comment: Проблема в сайте или в вашем понимании работы сайта. Дайте на него ссылку чтоли. Стоит предварительно через браузер протестировать вход на разные страницы сайта и посмотреть коды ответов в инспекторе браузера.

Comment: В исходном вопросе я указал - HttpClient дает отклик "200", как при наличии искомого файла, так и при подмене этого файла страницей 404. Это по началу ввело меня в ступор и вынудило задать вопрос здесь. Дествительно, проблемы такого поведения могут крыться, как в настройке сервера (например, не по всем стандартам дает сигнал о своих действиях наружу), так и в поведнии HttpClient, которому, в общем, плевать что с файлом, если есть что прожевать (наметки на такое поведение я видел, пока читал тематическую информацию).

Comment: Но позже я обновил свой вопрос, поскольку нашел способ выяснить объективное состояние файла на сервере с помощью HttpURLConnection.

Ковырять задачу в сторону коррективы работы самого сервера - не считаю хорошим подходом, сервера разные, все не перенастроишь. Если кто сможет развить и упростить решение задачи на примере сферического коня в вакууме - будет хорошо, потому вопрос не закрываю. Но конкретно свою задачу я решил.

Comment: кроме страницы с ошибкой 404 на сервере нужно устанавливать код ответа в 404, а не в 200, что вы собственно, не делаете.

Comment: Т.е. Вы предлагаете скорректировать страницу 404 или что-то подкрутить на сервере (что именно?). Сервер не мой, аренда на platforma.ru, как работает серверная часть не в курсе, все, до чего есть доступ - замена страницы 404.html  
В вопросах работы с серверами я не понимаю ровным счетом ничего. Чтобы написать в поддержку и попросить сменить отклик (если это в принципе возможно) - нужно понять как этот запрос просто и внятно сформулировать, хотя я про прежнему не считаю верным подход, решать эту задачу со стороны сервера.

Comment: @Zmeyk исправить проблему на стороне сервера - как раз правильный подход. А у себя с бубном танцевать чтобы заработало - это вынужденная мера. Попросите в техподдержке, чтобы они поменяли в настройках севера код с 200 на 404. А чтобы не париться с техподдержкой лучше возьмите недорогой хостинг на выделенном виртуальном сервере. Там сами сможете все настраивать и править.

Answer (score 1):

> От безысходности, я даже страницу 404 переделал

Насколько я понимаю, у Вас есть доступ к сайту.

`response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` возвращает код ответа сервера. Если вы переделали страницу 404, то, возможно, код 404 не отсылается правильно.

Убедитесь, что в вашей странице 404, которую Вы переделали имеется код: 
`header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")`. Или добавьте эту страницу в текст вопроса.